# SO_TIMEOUT in non blocking channel in netty

Tags: netty

Does the SO_TIMEOUT expire the Non blocking channel , if a channel doesn't receive a read/response in timeout millis?

```
bootstrap.group(workerGroup).channel(NioSocketChannel.class).
.handler(channelInitializer).option(ChannelOption.SO_TIMEOUT, 100);
```

Also, is the option applicable for server channel also? like:

```
serverBootstrap.group(bossGroup, workerGroup).channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class).
localAddress(new InetSocketAddress(8800)).childHandler(serverChannelInitializer).
option(ChannelOption.SO_TIMEOUT, 100).bind().sync();
```

Comment: It only has effect in blocking mode. Timeouts in non-blocking mode are a contradiction in terms.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No. `SO_TIMEOUT` has effect only for OIO socket transport.  You should use `IdleStateHandler` and handle an `IdleStateEvent` in your `userEventTriggered()` implementation.