# How to set a timeout in Spring 5 WebFlux WebClient

Tags: spring, reactor, spring-webflux, reactor-netty

I'm trying to set timeout on my WebClient, here is the current code :

```
SslContext sslContext = SslContextBuilder.forClient().trustManager(InsecureTrustManagerFactory.INSTANCE).build();

ClientHttpConnector httpConnector = new ReactorClientHttpConnector(opt -> {
    opt.sslContext(sslContext);
    HttpClientOptions option = HttpClientOptions.builder().build();
    opt.from(option);
});
return WebClient.builder().clientConnector(httpConnector).defaultHeader("Authorization", xxxx)
                .baseUrl(this.opusConfig.getBaseURL()).build();
```

I need to add timeout and also pooling strategy, I was thinking of something like that :

```
PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager cm = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();
cm.setMaxTotal(this.applicationConfig.getHttpClientMaxPoolSize());
cm.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(this.applicationConfig.getHttpClientMaxPoolSize());
cm.closeIdleConnections(this.applicationConfig.getServerIdleTimeout(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

RequestConfig requestConfig = RequestConfig.custom().setSocketTimeout(this.applicationConfig.getHttpClientSocketTimeout())
        .setConnectTimeout(this.applicationConfig.getHttpClientConnectTimeout())
        .setConnectionRequestTimeout(this.applicationConfig.getHttpClientRequestTimeout()).build();

CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setDefaultRequestConfig(requestConfig).setConnectionManager(cm).build();
```

But I can't figure out how to set the httpClient in my webclient

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The WebFlux `WebClient` doesn't use Apache Commons HTTP Client. Although you might be able to implement one solution via custom `ClientHttpConnector`. The existing `ReactorClientHttpConnector` is based on the Netty. So, consider to use Netty options to configure the client, e.g.:

```
ReactorClientHttpConnector connector =
            new ReactorClientHttpConnector(options ->
                    options.option(ChannelOption.SO_TIMEOUT, this.applicationConfig.getHttpClientConnectTimeout()));
```

or

```
.onChannelInit(channel -> channel.config().setConnectTimeoutMillis(this.applicationConfig.getHttpClientConnectTimeout()))
```

**UPDATE**

We also can use `ReadTimeoutHandler`:

```
.onChannelInit(channel -> 
        channel.pipeline()
           .addLast(new ReadTimeoutHandler(this.applicationConfig.getHttpClientConnectTimeout())))
```

Comment: This seems to be what I'm looking for, just a quick question is that the connect timeout or the request timeout. Any idea how I could set up the connection pool size ? thanks for your help

Comment: There is `poolResources()` in the `reactor.ipc.netty.options.ClientOptions.Builder` The `requestTimeout` is indeed equal to the `ChannelOption.SO_TIMEOUT`. The `connectTimeoutMillis` is definitely about connection.

Comment: Yeah I saw the poolResources(), I have to admit I have no idea how to use it :/ any idea ?

Comment: I tried : options.poolResources(PoolResources.fixed("myPool", this.applicationConfig.getHttpClientMaxPoolSize()));
Is that the correct way ?

Comment: When using the SO_TIMEOUT option, I'm getting following warnings logged:

 `Unknown channel option 'SO_TIMEOUT' for channel '[id: 0xa716fcb2]'`

Any hints on this @ArtemBilan ?

Comment: You might use some incompatible dependencies. Be sure just rely on what Reactor-Netty provides

Comment: hmm just using boot 2.0

Comment: Well, that sounds like an independent SO question, please

Comment: with which netty / reacter version do you have tested this?

Comment: This doesn't work for NIO channels and is imho therefore not an correct answer

Comment: Try `CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS` instead then

Comment: The api seems to have changed, here's how it works now https://stackoverflow.com/a/53781016/3993662

Answer (score 26):

To set the read and connect timeout I use the method below, because the SO_TIMEOUT option is not available for channels using NIO (and giving the warning `Unknown channel option 'SO_TIMEOUT' for channel '[id: 0xa716fcb2]'`)

```
ReactorClientHttpConnector connector = new ReactorClientHttpConnector(
          options -> options.option(ChannelOption.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, 2000)
                            .compression(true)
                            .afterNettyContextInit(ctx -> {
                                ctx.addHandlerLast(new ReadTimeoutHandler(5000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS));
                            }));
return WebClient.builder()
                .clientConnector(connector)
                .build();
```

Comment: Upvoted. This should be the correct answer.
c.f. https://stackoverflow.com/a/22897119/839733

Comment: Great! But ReactorClientHttpConnector has changed in WebFlux 5.1.

Answer (score 24):

ReactorClientHttpConnector API changed in version [Spring WebFlux 5.1](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/client/reactive/ReactorClientHttpConnector.html#ReactorClientHttpConnector-reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClient-).

So I do the following (Kotlin syntax, based on @joshiste example):

```
val tcpClient = TcpClient.create()
    .option(ChannelOption.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, 10_000)
    .doOnConnected { connection ->
        connection.addHandlerLast(ReadTimeoutHandler(10))
            .addHandlerLast(WriteTimeoutHandler(10))
    }

val myWebClient = webClientBuilder
    .clientConnector(ReactorClientHttpConnector(HttpClient.from(tcpClient)))
    .baseUrl(myEndPoint)
    .build()
```

UPDATE 2021

HttpClient.from in deprecated in last version of Reactive Netty. It was copying the configuration of the tcpClient. Now we can configure httpClient directly.

```
val httpClient = HttpClient.create()
    .option(ChannelOption.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, 10_000)
    .doOnConnected { connection ->
        connection.addHandlerLast(ReadTimeoutHandler(10))
            .addHandlerLast(WriteTimeoutHandler(10))
    }

val myWebClient = webClientBuilder
    .clientConnector(ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient))
    .baseUrl(myEndPoint)
    .build()
```

Comment: When using your solution I face```the method from(TcpClient) from the type HttpClient is deprecated```. Seems like the ```from(TcpClient)``` is deprecated too.

Answer (score 16):

As Spring Webflux was updated, here is a solution that works for Java (based on the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53781016/2852528) for Kotlin):

```
TcpClient timeoutClient = TcpClient.create()
    .option(ChannelOption.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, SECONDS*1000)
    .doOnConnected(
        c -> c.addHandlerLast(new ReadTimeoutHandler(SECONDS))
              .addHandlerLast(new WriteTimeoutHandler(SECONDS)));
return webClientBuilder.baseUrl(YOUR_URL)
       .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(HttpClient.from(timeoutClient)))
       .build();
```

**UPDATE 2021**

since `HttpClient.from(TcpClient)` is deprectaed now it's even easier:

```java
return WebClient.builder()
                .baseUrl(YOUR_URL)
                .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(HttpClient.create()
                                                                          .option(ChannelOption.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, SECONDS * 1000)
                                                                          .doOnConnected(c -> c.addHandlerLast(new ReadTimeoutHandler(SECONDS))
                                                                                               .addHandlerLast(new WriteTimeoutHandler(SECONDS)))))
                .build();
```

Comment: Quite helpful, however `.option(ChannelOption.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, SECONDS*10)`  I think the 10 should be 1000.

Comment: When using your solution I face```the method from(TcpClient) from the type HttpClient is deprecated```. Seems like the ```from(TcpClient)``` is deprecated too

Comment: @AbhinandanMadaan amended

Comment: @SerhiiPovísenko what about setConnectionRequestTimeout?

Comment: @EugeneShymko pardon, I do not understand the question

Comment: @SerhiiPovísenko configuration in the question have parameter added setConnectionRequestTimeout, I don't see same\similar configuration in WebClient

Comment: @EugeneShymko but the question is about  Spring 5 WebFlux WebClient, not Apache RequestConfig isn't it?

Comment: @SerhiiPovísenko well exactly. How to configure webclient with equivalent configuration as example with Apache requestConfig. So the question for me is webClient have equivalent configuration of setConnectionRequestTimeout from Apache requestConfig

Comment: @EugeneShymko unfortunately so far I am aware it does not

Answer (score 4):

With Spring Webflux 5.1.8 I ran into problems yielding the error messages below using the answer from [mcoolive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46235512/spring-5-webflux-how-to-set-a-timeout-on-webclient/53781016#53781016) when executing multiple subsequent tests that uses the `WebClient`.

> Force-closing a channel whose registration task was not accepted by an
>   event loop 
>   Failed to submit a listener notification task. Event loop shut down?

Adding a connection provider and loop resources solved my problem:

```java
final ConnectionProvider theTcpClientPool = ConnectionProvider.elastic("tcp-client-pool");
final LoopResources theTcpClientLoopResources = LoopResources.create("tcp-client-loop");

final TcpClient theTcpClient = TcpClient
    .create(theTcpClientPool)
    .option(ChannelOption.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, 5000)
    .runOn(theTcpClientLoopResources)
    .doOnConnected(theConnection -> {
        theConnection.addHandlerLast(new ReadTimeoutHandler(mTimeoutInMillisec, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS));
        theConnection.addHandlerLast(new WriteTimeoutHandler(mTimeoutInMillisec, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS));
    });

WebClient theWebClient = WebClient.builder()
    .baseUrl(mVfwsServerBaseUrl)
    .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(HttpClient.from(theTcpClient)))
    .build();
```

Comment: When using your solution I face```the method from(TcpClient) from the type HttpClient is deprecated```. Seems like the ```from(TcpClient)``` is deprecated too

Comment: I suggest taking a look at the documentation (JavaDoc) of the deprecated method. There is an example on how to replace the deprecated from() method in there.

Answer (score 3):

Here's how I did it (thanks to @Artem)

```
SslContext sslContext = SslContextBuilder.forClient().trustManager(InsecureTrustManagerFactory.INSTANCE).build();

        ClientHttpConnector httpConnector = new ReactorClientHttpConnector(options -> {
            options.sslContext(sslContext);
            options.option(ChannelOption.SO_TIMEOUT, this.applicationConfig.getHttpClientRequestTimeout());
            options.option(ChannelOption.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, this.applicationConfig.getHttpClientConnectTimeout());
            options.poolResources(PoolResources.fixed("myPool", this.applicationConfig.getHttpClientMaxPoolSize()));
        });

        return WebClient.builder().clientConnector(httpConnector).defaultHeader("Authorization", "xxxx")
                .baseUrl(this.config.getBaseURL()).build();
```

Comment: This is not working with Spring 5.1, ReactorClientHttpConnector does not allow options to be set anymore!

Answer (score 2):

Based on the above comment if you want to add a Socket Timeout just add it as another option in the same timeoutClient.

```
TcpClient timeoutClient = TcpClient.create()
    .option(ChannelOption.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, SECONDS*10) //Connect Timeout
    .option(ChannelOption.SO_TIMEOUT,1000) // Socket Timeout
    .doOnConnected(
        c -> c.addHandlerLast(new ReadTimeoutHandler(SECONDS))
              .addHandlerLast(new WriteTimeoutHandler(SECONDS)));
return webClientBuilder.baseUrl(YOUR_URL)
       .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(HttpClient.from(timeoutClient)))
       .build();
```

Comment: Are you recommending both setting `SO_TIMEOUT` and adding `ReadTimeoutHandler`?

Comment: When using your solution I face```the method from(TcpClient) from the type HttpClient is deprecated```. Seems like the ```from(TcpClient)``` is deprecated too

Answer (score 2):

Rather than creating your own `WebClient.Builder`, you can provide a custom `ReactorNettyHttpClientMapper` which is going to be applied to the default `WebClient.Builder`:

```kotlin
@Configuration
class MyAppConfiguration {

    @Bean
    fun reactorNettyHttpClientMapper(): ReactorNettyHttpClientMapper {
        return ReactorNettyHttpClientMapper { httpClient ->
            httpClient.tcpConfiguration { tcpClient ->
                tcpClient.option(ChannelOption.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, 30_000)
                    .doOnConnected { connection ->
                        connection.addHandlerLast(ReadTimeoutHandler(60))
                            .addHandlerLast(WriteTimeoutHandler(60))
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use overloaded block() method which accepts a timeout on Mono object.
Or there is a timeout() method directly available on Mono object.

```
WebClient webClient = WebClient.builder()
              .baseUrl( "https://test.com" )
              .defaultHeader( HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE )
              .build(); 

webClient.post()
              .uri( "/services/some/uri" )
              .body( Mono.just( YourEntityClassObject ), YourEntityClass.class )
              .retrieve()
              .bodyToMono( String.class )
              .timeout(Duration.ofMillis( 5000 )) // option 1
              .block(Duration.ofMillis( 5000 )); // option 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin Syntax!!

```
webClient
.post()
.body(BodyInserters.fromObject(body))
.headers(headersSetter)
.retrieve()
.bodyToMono<SomeClass>()
.timeout(Duration.ofSeconds(30)) /// specify timeout duration
.doOnNext {
    logger.info{ "log something"}
}
.onErrorMap { throwable ->
    logger.error{"do some transformation"}
    throwable
}
```