# Set connection timeout using Spring Webflux Reactive WebClient

Tags: spring, spring-webflux

What is the correct way to set a (connection) timeout for the (default) WebClient?

Is it enough to just use `Mono#timeout(Duration)` method on the resulting Mono (or Flux)? Or does this lead to a possible memory / connection leak?

Thanks in advance!

(The answers from [Spring 5 webflux how to set a timeout on Webclient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46235512/spring-5-webflux-how-to-set-a-timeout-on-webclient) do not work!)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring 5 webflux how to set a timeout on Webclient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46235512/spring-5-webflux-how-to-set-a-timeout-on-webclient)

Comment: I know the post you mentioned; even the accepted answer does *not* work (and is so ugly).

Answer (score 10):

As of Reactor Netty 0.8 and Spring Framework 5.1, you can set connection, read & write timeouts like the following:

```
TcpClient tcpClient = TcpClient.create()
                 .option(ChannelOption.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, 1000) // Connection Timeout
                 .doOnConnected(connection ->
                         connection.addHandlerLast(new ReadTimeoutHandler(10)) // Read Timeout
                                   .addHandlerLast(new WriteTimeoutHandler(10))); // Write Timeout
WebClient webClient = WebClient.builder()
    .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(HttpClient.from(tcpClient)))
    .build();
```

Comment: changing values new WriteTimeoutHandler(10) doesn't change default timeout of webflux 10sec

Answer (score 2):

For now, `WebClient` does not offer that option as a top-level configuration option. You have to configure that at the underlying HTTP client library.

So the answer to the other question is right. But in your case, you probably need to change the connection timeout, not the socket timeout (or both).

```
ReactorClientHttpConnector connector =
            new ReactorClientHttpConnector(options ->
                    options.option(ChannelOption.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, 2000));
WebClient webClient = WebClient.builder().clientConnector(connector).build();
```