# Handler for connect timeout

Tags: spring, spring-webflux

I want to use Spring 5 Web client for REST connections.

```
 WebClient.Builder builder = WebClient.builder().baseUrl(gatewayUrl);
    ClientHttpConnector httpConnector = new ReactorClientHttpConnector(opt -> opt.sslContext(sslContext));
    builder.clientConnector(httpConnector);
```

How I can implement handler for connection timeout?

I checked the code [here](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/master/client/rest/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/client/RestClientBuilder.java) but I can't find a solution.

Comment: Are you using Spring Boot? `RestClient` is an ElasticSearch class - were you trying to use Spring `RestTemplate` or `WebClient` instead?

Comment: I'm using WebClient.

Comment: Then I don't understand your question - right now it's referring to ES RestClient.

Comment: It's from the package import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient;

Comment: I know - could you update your question then? Right now it’s about the elasticsearch client.

Comment: I updated the code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set connection timeout using Spring Webflux Reactive WebClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48096573/set-connection-timeout-using-spring-webflux-reactive-webclient)