# Proper way to setup request specific read timeout on Spring 5 WebClient

Tags: spring-cloud-netflix, spring-webflux, hystrix, reactor-netty

### Context

I'm trying to find the best way to combine Spring 5 `WebClient` and `Hystrix`. Using Hystrix, I set different timeouts for different type of requests done by the `WebClient`.

When `Hystrix` reaches it's timeout, I also want to make sure that `WebClient` closes its connection. Previously when using `AsyncHttpClient`, this was done by setting a `requestTimeout` before performing the specific call. However, setting the request timeout on `WebClient` is much more complicated and needs to be done on the `ClientHttpConnector` according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46242321/2999211).

[Brian Cozel mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49107545) that it is optimal to share the same `ClientHttpConnector` throughout the application. However, because the request specific timeout needs to be set on the `ClientHttpConnector`, this does not seem possible.

### Question

In Spring's Reactive `WebClient`, is there a proper way to set request specific timeouts, but still use a single `ClientHttpConnector`?

Comment: Could you simplify your question? This seems to be 3 questions in one - please focus on a single one: 1) does spring cloud netflix support webflux? 2) What are the different timeout options with WebClient and how do they differ? 3) Is there a way to set a response timeout on a per request basis with WebClient

Comment: Hi @BrianClozel, thanks for the quick response. I've tried to clarify my question in an edit. My question is 3), setting a response timeout on a per request basic, while still reusing the same `ClientHttpConnector` as you suggest doing for performance reasons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The timeout operations that you can configure on the client connector are quite low level: they're about socket/connection timeouts. This configuration cannot be done at the request level, since connections might be shared and reused in a connection pool.

This question is about response timeouts, since you seem to care about the amount of time to get the response, on a per request basis.

In this case, you can use the `timeout` operator on a per request basis:

```
Mono<UserData> result = this.webClient.get()
                .uri("/user")
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(UserData.class)
                .timeout(Duration.ofSeconds(10));
```

The timeout operator will throw a `TimeoutException` in the pipeline; you can use one of the `onError*` operators to define what should be done in those cases. Alternatively, you can directly use the `timeout(Duration, Mono)` variant that provides a fallback.

Comment: Hystrix will also throw some kind of timeout exception, but reaching this timeout doesn't mean the HTTP client connection is closed immediately, right? Or is that the case?

Comment: It is the case as far as I know for reactor-netty. But it depends on the underlying client library, if it is configured for connection pooling, etc.